# Setting working directory in NetLogo

Tags: netlogo

Is there some way to set a working directory preference to NetLogo for file opening, saving, etc.? It defaults to C:\Users\my-name-here every time. I am using NetLogo 6.0.1 on Win10.

I have tried putting shortcuts in the working directory with the "start in" directory filled in and also leaving it blank, but neither work.  NetLogo ignores the "start in" directory information.

Answer (score 0):

There is not. However, File -> Recent files should alleviate the pain for quickly opening models you've worked on recently.

Answer (score 0):

My best solution so far (better than nothing) is this:

One time -- create a placeholder nlogo file: 
Open Netlogo, then click File>Save (i.e., WorkDir.nlogo), close NetLogo.
It will be in c:\Users\your-name-here probably.
Move WorkDir.nlogo to your preferred working directory.

Thereafter: 
1) Use File Explorer or similar to get to where you put the placeholder nlogo file
1) Open the placeholder file in NetLogo (double click).
2) Immediately click on File>SAVE AS... and replace Yes.  No need to change the file name.

That's it. So long as this instance of Netlogo is open, NetLogo will use that location as the working directory.

Note: You have to use File> Save As.  Clicking on File>SAVE will NOT change the working directory.

If you put a shortcut in C:\Users\your-name-here to your working directory or to the placeholder in the working directory, you can start NetLogo, click file open, use the shortcut to get to your working directory, then open and save-as the placeholder nlogo file.